# Nothing happens when trying to execute .exe files c++ project g2o

Tags: c++, g2o

[image]I generated the .exe files by running 'make' for the c++ project g2o. However when I try executing them, a black window appears for a short time, but nothing else happens. Does it mean something went wrong when creating them? I generated them again using the source code from https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o, which resulted in the same problem.

Comment: Where is the g2o folder in relation to the source file that failed to compile?

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: What platform are you using? Did you already build the shared libraries using cmake? ([Instructions](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o#compilation).)

Comment: When you added the path, did you include "g2o/stuff" in it?  I just want to confirm that the path you set + '/' + g2o/stuff/macros.h gives the whole path you expect.

Comment: I tried on some other projects and I at least got some .exe files now. The problem is when I try to execute them a black window appears for a short time, that`s all. Is this project specific, or does it mean something went wrong when creating the exe files?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how I get these .exe working, I need it desperately for a project.